# Missing Attribute 'type' in Spring WebClient Response for Microservice Communication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webclient, pageable

I want to use WebClient to retrieve a page from another microservice. When I directly request the microservice using Postman, the response includes the `type` attribute among other fields in the `content` section. However, when I make the request via WebClient, the `type` attribute (and some other fields) disappear from the `content` section. The `content` is a list of objects of the abstract class `Account`. which uses `JsonSubTypes` for polymorphic deserialization.

Can someone help me identify the mistake and understand why the "type" attribute disappears when using WebClient to call the microservice?

Here are the sample responses for comparison:

**Responses**

*Response from `http://localhost:8080/api/v1/accounts`*

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "savingsBook",
            "id": 108,
            "accountNumber": 99781944,
            ...
        }
    ], "pageable": {
        ...
    }, "totalPages": ...
    ...
}
```

*Response from `http://localhost:8081/accounts`*

```
{
    "content": [
        {
            "id": 108,
            "accountNumber": 99781944,
            ...
        }
    ], "pageable": {
        ...
    }, "totalPages": ...
    ...
}
```

**Code-Snippets:**

*8080's account controller*

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
public <T extends Account> Page<T> getAccounts(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize, @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false) String sortBy) {
    if (page == null) {
        page = 0;
    }
    if (pageSize == null) {
        pageSize = 10;
    }
    if (sortBy == null) {
        Page<T> p = accountService.getAccounts(page, pageSize);
        return new PageImpl<T>(p.getContent(), p.getPageable(), p.getTotalElements()) {};

    } else {
        Sort sort = Sort.by(sortBy);
        Page<T> p = accountService.getAccounts(page, pageSize, sort);
        return new PageImpl<T>(p.getContent(), p.getPageable(), p.getTotalElements()) {};
    }
}
```

*8081 Account Controler*

```
@GetMapping
public  <T extends Account> Page<T> getAllAccounts(@RequestParam(value = "page", required = false) Integer page, 
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "pageSize", required = false) Integer pageSize,
                                                   @RequestParam(value = "sortBy", required = false) String sortBy) {   
     if (page == null) {
         page = 0;
     }
     if (pageSize == null) {
         pageSize = 10;
     }
     if (sortBy == null) {
         return accountService.getAllAccounts(page, pageSize);
     } else {
         return accountService.getAllAccounts(page, pageSize, sortBy);
     }
}
```

*8081 AccountService*

```
public <T extends Account> Page<T> getAllAccounts(Integer pageNumber, Integer pageSize) {
    ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<T>> typeReference = new ParameterizedTypeReference<CustomPageImpl<T>>(){};
    System.out.println("Anfrage an: " + addr + "/accounts/");
    System.out.println(client.get().uri("/accounts/").retrieve().bodyToMono(typeReference).block().getContent());
    Page<T> prodData = (CustomPageImpl<T>)(client.get().uri("/accounts/").retrieve().bodyToMono(typeReference).block());
    return prodData;
}
```

*CustomPageImpl (got it from another StackOverflow-Post)*

```
public class CustomPageImpl<T> extends PageImpl<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @JsonCreator(mode = JsonCreator.Mode.PROPERTIES)
    public CustomPageImpl(@JsonProperty("content") List<T> content,
            @JsonProperty("number") int number,
            @JsonProperty("size") int size,
            @JsonProperty("totalElements") Long totalElements,
            @JsonProperty("pageable") JsonNode pageable,
            @JsonProperty("last") boolean last,
            @JsonProperty("totalPages") int totalPages,
            @JsonProperty("sort") JsonNode sort,
            @JsonProperty("first") boolean first,
            @JsonProperty("numberOfElements") int numberOfElements){
        super(content, PageRequest.of(number, size) , totalElements);
    }
    public CustomPageImpl(List<T> content, Pageable pageable, long total) {
        super(content, pageable, total);
    }

    public CustomPageImpl(List<T> content) {
        super(content);
    }

    public CustomPageImpl() {
        super(new ArrayList<>());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found an answer to this question on my own.**

The problem is the fact, that Account is abstract and has json subtypes. By replacing `public class CustomPageImpl<T> extends PageImpl<T>` by `public class CustomPageImpl<T extends Account> extends PageImpl<T>` I was able to solve this issue. Now I receive the type as planned.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to implement your CustomPageImpl you can register a module in Jackson ObjectMapper.

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public ObjectMapper objectMapper() {
        return new ObjectMapper()
            .registerModule(new PageJacksonModule())
            .registerModule(new SortJacksonModule());
    }

}
```

`SortJacksonModule` and `PageJacksonModule` comes from `org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support`

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-openfeign</artifactId>
</dependency>
```